# how to populate database using python faker

Tags: python, psycopg2, psql

I am trying to populate a table using python faker and I am getting this error  . Here is my code

```
import psycopg2
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="testdb", user="****", password="****", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
print "Opened database successfully"
cur = conn.cursor()

for i in range (10):
    Id =fake.random_digit_not_null()
    name = fake.name()
    age=fake.random_number(digits=None) 
    adress =fake.address()
    salary = fake.random_int(min=0, max=9999)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) \
      VALUES (Id,name,age,adress,salary)");

conn.commit()
print "Records created successfully";
conn.close()
```

here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fakegenerator.py", line 16, in <module>
    VALUES (Id,name,age,adress,salary)");
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: ...OMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)       VALUES (Id,name,ag...
                                                             ^
HINT:  There is a column named "id" in table "company", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not filling in the values into your query, instead you're sending the string as-is to the database. This would actually fill your query with values:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (Id, name, age, adress, salary));
```

This wraps the variables filled with the values you want to insert into a tuple and let's psycopg2 handle quoting your strings correctly which is less work for you and keeps you safe from SQL injection, should you use your code as a base for productive code. This is documented in [the module's documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#basic-module-usage).

Answer (score -1):

the sql request in cur.execute seems to be a problem try this

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) \
  VALUES ({},{},{},{},{})".format(Id,name,age,adress,salary));
```

Comment: You should not use string concatenation when inserting into a DB. https://xkcd.com/327/ .. Psycopg2 states: `Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.`